# TortoiseGit won't let me access my /trunk D:

Tags: git, github, msysgit, tortoisegit, trunk

I have no problem cloning/commiting from my ssh link, but if I ask tortoiseGit to do it on shhLink/trunk i'll get a 128 error.

"fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Any idea why?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there is a branch called trunk on your sshLink remote? So, you are having no problems committing to the master branch then?

Comment: Can you provide any other information? Perhaps you have access to the SSH logs on the server? It's kind of hard to reproduce or even guess with the information provided.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow my key was not being handled properly.

I had to manually go in putty configuration, set my key and ask tortoiseGit to let putty decide what to do.